# using a non literal as a template string in javascript

Tags: javascript

Given this?

```
var v = 10;
var template = "testing ${v}...";
```

How do I achieve the same result as the following template string.

```
var result = `testing ${v}...`;
```

The template string is stored in a variable, and not a literal template string.

Is there a method to apply a template string when the template string is stored in a variable, and not literal?

Comment: you can create a function to search and replace the dynamic variable with dynamic value

Comment: [`String.prototype.supplant()`](https://gist.github.com/pbroschwitz/3891293)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var v = 10;
var template = "testing ${v}...";

var output = template.replace("${v}", `${v}`);

alert(output);
```

Comment: I need the template string to be opaque. If I have to search and replace each possible variable, I might as well not use the template string, and just do a regular search and replace.

Comment: @jim - Javascript doesn't have automatic string interpolation. The closest you'll be able to get is manual interpolation with `eval`: `var a = 1; eval('var b = "testing '+a+'...";'); console.log(b);`